# I haven’t enjoyed myself so much for a long time. (What does this sentence mean?)

Tags: sentence-meaning

> "I haven’t enjoyed myself so much for a long time." [from a dictionary]

The sentence above is clearly negated by haven't(have **not**).

Does this sentence mean

1. the person has not enjoyed himself until now (for example, he only studies), or
2. the person has already enjoyed himself a lot but this happened after having passed a long time without enjoyment?

My dictionary translation is #2.

Answer (score 3):

"I haven't enjoyed myself so much" suggests that I have enjoyed myself, but to a smaller degree. The entire sentence is saying that while I have enjoyed myself, it has been a long time since I enjoyed myself as much as this (so much).

Compare "It hasn't been as hot as this for a long time". If it is a 45 degree summer day in Wagga Wagga, this would be saying that the temperature has not reached 45 degrees for a long time. There may well have been days of 35 degrees or more, which would still be hot days, just not "as hot as this".

Comment: so much=as much as this?

Comment: @BEBYGONES Yes, exactly.

Comment: Why there is no such explanation in a dictionary?

Comment: @stangdon What if I say "I haven't enjoyed myself much for a long time."? (without 'to')

Comment: @BEBYGONES  Dictionaries do list this meaning.  [**so**: *to an indicated or suggested extent or degree*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/so)  "I haven't enjoyed myself much" (I assume you meant "without *so*") would mean that I have not enjoyed myself very much *at all*, not just "to this degree".

Comment: Only the largest dictionaries can include every possible phrase that a word might occur in